# Why PHP script execution gets serialized?

Tags: nginx, php

I am using CakePHP3 -  Nginx + PHP7 on Windows8.

I have spawned multiple php-cgi processes for parralel execution. However what I have noticed, that in case of multiple concurrent ajax request from single host, request gets serialized. 
I can confirm that there are some CPU usage spikes on multiple php-cgi instances, so it looks like requests are handled in parallel, but still they are serialized somehow. Any ideas what is serializing the calls?

Script does a simple repeatable and fast select from the DB that returns single row each.

Here is request timeline:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is coming from the server ? I would suspect the browser cache or the javascript

Comment: @Dom can you elaborate on that? How can browser cache delay execution of request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Google Chrome limits 6 connections per host at the same time.

Ref: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12066

Comment: But it is on firefox....

Comment: but just checked the limitation for firefox and it is 6 as well. Accepting answer as it was on the right track.